# header location not working in my php code

Tags: php, header

i have this code,why my header location not working?
its a form of updating and editing and deleting some pages in my control panel...and i have an index.php file in the same folder of form.php...any help please?()i tryed to put the header after the editing and deleting...and still go to the form page not the index...

```
<?php
include "../../includes/site_includes.php";
//send
if ((isset($_POST["send"])) && ($_POST["send"] == 1)) {
    $pageid = $_POST["page_id"];
    $pagetitle = $_POST["page_title"];
    $nameinmenu = $_POST["page_menu_name"];
    $nameinurl = $_POST["page_name_url"];
    $link = $_POST["page_link"];
    $picture = $_POST["page_pic"];
    $desc = $_POST["page_desc"];
    $content = $_POST["page_content"];
}
if ((isset($_POST["act"])) && ($_POST["act"] == "add")) {
    $sql = insertpage();
    if ($result = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        $result->bind_param("sssssss", $pagetitle, $nameinmenu, $nameinurl, $link, $picture, $desc, $content);
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();
        $rows = $result->num_rows;
    }
}
////edit
if ((isset($_GET["act"])) && ($_GET["act"] == "edit")) {
    $sql = getfrompages();
    if ($result = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        $rekza = $_GET["id"];
        $result->bind_param("i", $rekza);
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();
        $rowsZ = $result->num_rows;
    }
    if ($rowsZ > 0) {
        $row = fetch($result);
        $pageid = $row[0]["page_id"];
        $pagetitle = $row[0]["page_title"];
        $nameinmenu = $row[0]["page_menu_name"];
        $nameinurl = $row[0]["page_name_url"];
        $link = $row[0]["page_link"];
        $picture = $row[0]["page_pic"];
        $desc = $row[0]["page_desc"];
        $content = $row[0]["page_content"];
    }
}
if ((isset($_GET["act"])) && ($_GET["act"] == "delete")) {
    $thedelid = $_GET["id"];
    $sql2 = delpage();
    if ($result2 = $mysqli->prepare($sql2)) {
        $result2->bind_param("i", $thedelid);
        $result2->execute();
        $result2->store_result();
        $rowsZ2 = $result2->num_rows;
    }
}
header('location: index.php');
exit();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> pages add </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
 </head>

 <body>
<form method="post" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">title</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="page_title" value="<?=$pagetitle?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">name in menu</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="page_menu_name" value="<?=$nameinmenu?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">name in url</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="page_name_url" value="<?=$nameinurl?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">link</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="page_link" value="<?=$link?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">picture</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="page_pic" value="<?=$picture?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">description</td>
                <td><textarea name="page_desc"><?=$desc?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">content</td>
                <td><textarea name="page_content"><?=$content?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="act" value="<?=$_GET["act"]?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="<?=$pageid?>" />
                <input type="submit" value="add" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**solved:**
with @ Mihai Iorga code i added ob_start();

Comment: Are you certain it's even getting executed at all? The condition might not even be true.

Comment: Define "not working". Is the code even being executed? Provide a ***minimal*** test case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The header() call is in an if() block, so it might not even be working in the first place.

Comment: not working i mean...with out redirect to index.php ... still in the same url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php

Comment: thank you everybody .. i solved it..

Comment: @michael You could accept the best answer. it will encourage others to help u and increase your reputation too.

Comment: Thanks to this question I realized I was forgetting `exit;` after my header location redirect. Fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

That is because you have an output:

```
?>
<?php
```

results in blank line output.

*header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP*

Combine all your PHP codes and make sure you don't have any spaces at the beginning of the file.

also after `header('location: index.php');` add `exit();` if you have any other scripts bellow.

Also move your redirect header after the last `if`.

If there is content, then you can also redirect by injecting javascript:

```
<?php
    echo "<script>window.location.href='target.php';</script>";
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Where you break your PHP code with `?><?php` it will result in a blank line. Combine them all line [here](http://codepad.org/mgs2zXI7)

Comment: @MihaiIorga: The newline in `?>\n<?php` is swallowed by the PHP parser, but there's a space at the very beginning of the code block...

Comment: Maybe you don't enter the last `if` .. move your header like [here](http://codepad.org/Jn6bTbHT)

Comment: mm...look at the new code i edited,this is my full code on the page!

Comment: but when i press add , there is no form in the page....look....i 'll put the form in the new code... please look at the new code after 2 mins

Comment: not only add...but also edit....all the actions that shoud be form in it...there is not form :\

Comment: maybe you have an extra space in `include "../../includes/site_includes.php";` check that file.

Comment: If you have your form bellow you should move your header like here:  http://codepad.org/2Rg0qtQN

Comment: still the same problem :S....the header is not working and still in the same page :S

Comment: add this before first: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);` and tell me what error it displays ?

Comment: @ Mihai Iorga thank you man.. i just added ob_start(); with your code ;)))

Answer (score 56):

Try adding `ob_start();` at the top of the code i.e. before the `include` statement.

Comment: It works, but can you explain why `ob_start()` solves the problem? I will upvote if you can.

Comment: Monster Combo Breaker!!

Answer (score 10):

just use `ob_start();` before include function it will help

Answer (score 9):

***Remove Space***

Correct : **header("Location: home.php");** or **header("Location:home.php");**

Incorrect : header("Location :home.php");

Remove space between Location and : **-->** header("Location(**remove space**): home.php");

Answer (score 6):

The function ob_start() will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer. So browser will not receive any output and the header will work.Also we should make sure that header() is used on the top of the code.

Answer (score 5):

```
ob_start();
```

should be added in the line 1 itself.
like in below example

```
<?php
ob_start(); // needs to be added here
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
// your code goes here
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
//code to save data in db goes here
}
header('location:index.php?msg=sav'); 
?>
```

adding it below html also doesnt work. like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
// your code goes here
</html>
<?php
ob_start(); // it doesnt work even if you add here
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
//code to save data in db goes here
}
header('location:index.php?msg=sav'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use following code and it works fine for me.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
       ob_start();
       header("Location: https://sitename.com/login.php");
       exit();
} else { 

// my further code 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same application on my localhost and on a shared server. On my localhost the redirects worked fine while on this shared server didn't. I checked the phpinfo and I saw what caused this:

[image]

While on my localhost I had this:

[image]

So I asked the system admin to increase that value and after he did that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

for me just add ob_start(); at the start of the file.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure this out: My php-file was encoded in UTF-8. And the BOM prevented header location to work properly. In Notepad++ I set the file encoding to "UTF-8 without BOM" and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Check if below are enabled

bz, mbstring, intl, ioncube_loader and Json extension.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Location` not `location`:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: mmm i didnt think its have any effects....but i solved it by adding ob_start(); man ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i created new config file with function 'ob_start()' and added this to my .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
header("Location:comments.php");
```

And it solve out..

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code, you are using a form and setting action to "", which I understand takes precedence over a header within the form.

I found rather using the action element within the form instead of header Location is one option. I assume you want different options on the link, thus the variable.

```
<?php $nextLink = "index.php"; ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $nextLink; ?>">
```

I suggest placing the variable outside a $_POST to start testing with.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was extra spaces after ?>

Removed the spaces, and voila it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i just added `ob_start();` before include anything and it worked !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Create config.php and put the code it will work

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["How do I write a good answer??"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). You might also want to learn about ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples"] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

So, the issue for me was echo statements. When I used echo to gauge what was going on, header stopped working.

When I tried putting ob_start(); just before the header() it didn't fix anything.

When I put ob_start(); at the top of the file just below my include statements, it fixed the issue. Of course my echo statements stopped working.

From my perspective, this is a massive deficiency in the Header() method. It makes troubleshooting more difficult and it sure cost me a lot of time.