# Refirect after successful login form PHP

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I have a simple login-form with username and password. The PHP after this form is this

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'global.php';    

// Grab User submitted information
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row["username"]==$username  && $row["password"]==$password)
{   
    echo 'ok';
}
else {
    echo 'not ok'; 
}
?>
```

After submitting, the form shows the correct message (ok or not ok) if the username and password exists, but I can't seem to do more than echoing.

When the user exists, the form has to redirect to the index.php-page. I tried to put this in the if-clause

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

but that doesn't work :(

When the user doesn't exist, it has to show a message on the login form. So I put this in the else-clause

```
$_SESSION['errors'] = array("Your username or password was incorrect."); 
header("Location: login.php");
```

This stores the message in the session, so when I put the following code on the login form

```
 <?php if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])): ?> 
    <div class="form-errors"> 
        <?php foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $error): ?> 
            <p><?php echo $error ?></p> 
        <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hoped this would work too, but nothing does, sadly. Can someone assist me?

Comment: It dosn't work is no accurate error description. Any PHP Error? Error Level set to show all? What happens in the Browser Console, when redirect should happen?

Comment: @Christian When I put the `header('Location: index.php');` in the if-clause, he just redirects to the (blank) action-page in my form.

This action-page contains this code:

`<?php
session_start();
include 'global.php';    

// Grab User submitted information
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row["username"]==$username  && $row["password"]==$password)
{   
    echo 'ok';
}
else {
    echo 'not ok'; 
}
?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have result

```
?>
<?php
```

header location not works in this case.

another way is using `ob_start();` at the top

```
ob_start();
header("Location: yourpage.php");
exit();
```

[Reference : **header location not working in my php code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525251/header-location-not-working-in-my-php-code)

Comment: ob_start() at the top did the trick for the redirect, thank you!

If the username doesn't exist, he stays on the login-page, but he doesn't seem to show the error.

Comment: you can store error in session or local variable and show every where you need. other way is you can redirect with header location and set msg as a query string to new page `header("Location: redirect.php?msg=loginError");` then in redirect page show error from `$_GET['msg']`

Comment: Thanks again! Your way also work, but I made it work like by putting this code in my login-form

   `<?php
         if( isset($_SESSION['errors']) )
{
        echo $_SESSION['errors'];

        unset($_SESSION['errors']);

}
?>`

If I could I'd upvote, but I'm missing some rep to do that, sry :)

Answer (score 0):

before header should not be any echo, var_dump, print_r or any html or any text
and write exit() after header

```
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```