# PHP header location redirect doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: php, ios, redirect, safari, header

I have a PHP script that is supposed to redirect to a dynamic fallback URL after having executed some code. I use it to redirect user to a specific URL i.e. after a successful log in. The code is:

```
header('Location: '. rawurldecode('/index.php?'));
```

This code works well on all 3 major browsers, however, the header-location simply does not work work on iPhone. I have tested on Safari and also Chrome for iOS : both won't work.

I have also tried hard-coded full-length URLs, without success.

```
header("Location: http://google.com/");
```

**EDIT**

I have tried to input the domain in the redirect statement. This seems to fix the problem on the mobile browsers, but now breaks on desktop browsers...

```
   header('Location: http:' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]. rawurldecode($_GET['redirect']));
```

Comment: just to be correct its header("Location: http://google.com/"); and not Header("Location: http://google.com/"); right

Comment: justrohu, that's correct. turns out my configs PHP accepts both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the javascript way of redirecting the page:

Example :

```
    echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>';
    die;
```

It may help ...!!

Comment: Thanks, using JavaScript works well. The only drawback is that the redirect occurs only after loading the body, hence the previous page is still visible for a second or so. Also, the die; statement as you mention is important to block the execution of other scripts on the page.

Comment: Good to know its work for you , happy to help ... :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525251/header-location-not-working-in-my-php-code

this can also be the other solution

Answer (score 0):

try this if you reload current page.

```
echo '<script>location.reload();</script>';
```