# Cannot Use Session Variable To Store Data

Tags: javascript, php

I have the a php file that contains the following

1. an html file which is used to collect data for a new user
2. php functions that validate the input data
3. javascript codes that alerts and prompt the user before data submission
4. after the validation process I want to move the input data to an insert.php to insert data into the database.

Below is the code

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION['login_user']) && $_SESSION['login_user'] != '')) {

header ("Location: loginForm.php");

}

$hash;
$salt;

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/templates/myjavascript.js"></script>

<title>Title of the document</title>
<script>
  window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("new_user_form").onsubmit=function(){

        if(this.pword.value === this.pword2.value)
           { alert("Are you sure you want to create a new user")
               return true;}
         else{ alert("Paswords must be the same ");
             return false;}
      }
  }

</script>
</head>
<div>
<body>

<section id="content">


<form align="center" class="form" action="create_user.php" method="post" id="new_user_form" name="new_user_form">

<ul>

<li>
<h2>Please Fill The Form</h2>

</li>



<li>
     <label for="username">User Name</label> 
        <input name="username" id="keyword" type="text" placeholder="type first name (required)" required />             

</li>

<li>
     <label for="pword">Password</label>
     <input name="pword" id="pword" type="password" placeholder="########" required />
</li>

<li>
     <label for="pword2">Confirm Password</label>
     <input name="pword2" id="pword2" type="password" placeholder="########" required />
</li>



<p>
          <input type = "reset" class="reset" name="submit"/>
          <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit" "/>
        </p>    

</section>

</ul>
</form>

</body>
</div>

<?php

 /* php function to check pasword policy 
     The password has to be alphanumeric and special characters minimum 8 and max 16               
                    */                   

function checkpwdPolicy(){

      if($_POST['pword'] === $_POST['pword2']) {

  if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,16}$/', $_POST['pword'])) {
  echo '<script> alert(" password requirement not met"); </script>';

} else{

 /* we use the session varible to store the hashed password and username   */
                                                      /
 $_SESSION['pwd'] = password_hash($_POST['pword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

 header ("Location: insert_user_table.php");
  }
} 
  else {echo "passwords do not match  "; }

}

 //tis is used to call the fucntion that checks the password policy                                      

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pword']) && isset($_POST['pword2']) )
{checkpwdPolicy();}


?>

</html>
```

How ever when I run the cod I get the following error displayed.
Below is the error.

[image]

The question is how to move the data to the file that will do the insertion of data into database.

Comment: place your `checkpwdPolicy()` before `<html>` on the file, that would solve your issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) // please _research_ error messages before asking – this has been discussed a gazillion times already.

Comment: @Disha V thanks your suggestion solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

if you put any thing or show anything  before session start command as well as before header("location: url"). it will not work.

simply

1. put "session_start();" top of the page.
2. dont show or use echo before header("Location: url");

another answer:  [header location not working in my php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525251/header-location-not-working-in-my-php-code)

Answer (score 1):

change your

```
<?PHP
```

to

```
<?php
```

remove spaces before it if any

```
session_start();
//remove this line
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login_user']) && $_SESSION['login_user'] != '')) {
//remove this line
header ("Location: loginForm.php");
//remove this line
}
```

remove spaces in between the above code.

or try this in place of your header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.assign('loginForm.php');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to start session at the beginning to avoid this warning message.

```
session_start();
```