# header location is not working, im stuck in the same page

Tags: mysqli, header

hey all i have this code, the query works totally fine but the header no please help , this is my code i appreciate it

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['login'])){

$username=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$hashedpass=md5($pass);

$query="SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$hashedpass'";
echo $query;
$run=mysqli_query($con, $query);

$rows=mysqli_num_rows($run);

if ($rows > 0){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
  }

}


?>
```

Username
                
            
             
                Password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [header location not working in my php code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525251/header-location-not-working-in-my-php-code)

Answer (score 0):

Try writing complete uri and delete exit
header('Location: http://www.domain/index.php');