# Session is filling but header not redirect when login

Tags: php, html, header

I'm sharing code. Please help me guys... İf correct username and password always coming line 47.I need location same page(this page.And I must running this code require_once "inc/default.php"; ). I marked line 47 with comment.I need first header running then running  require_once "inc/default.php"; on same page.I marked require code line 24.URL =this page link.İt's define on ayar.php
If you watch [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPadxCWNE6A) video you will know what I mean.

```
         <?php
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        define( "GUVENLIK", true );
        require_once "ayar.php";
        require_once "sistem.php";
        define( "ADMIN", true );
        
        function encryptIt( $q ) {
            $cryptKey = 'Barge';
            $qEncoded = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
            return ( $qEncoded );
        }
        
        function decryptIt( $q ) {
            $cryptKey = 'Barge';
            $qDecoded = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0" );
            return ( $qDecoded );
        }
        $r1 = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM uyeler WHERE uye_kadi = '$kadi' && uye_sifre = '$sifre'" ) );
        
        
        if ( $_SESSION[ 'login' ] == 'true' ) {
 /*Line 24*/           require_once "inc/default.php";
        } else {
        
            if ( $_POST ) {
                $kadi = p( "kadi" );
                $sifre = encryptIt( p( "sifre" ) );
        
                if ( !$kadi || !$sifre ) {
                    echo "Kullanıcı adı ve Şifre Boş Bırakılamaz..";
                } else {
                    $mysqli = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $pass, $db )or die( mysqli_error() );
                    mysqli_set_charset( $mysqli, "utf8" );
                    $sonuc = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM uyeler WHERE uye_kadi = '$kadi' and uye_sifre = '$sifre'" )->fetch_array();
                    $kullanici_id = $sonuc[ "uye_id" ];
                    $_SESSION[ 'kullanici_id' ] = $kullanici_id;
        
        
                    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM uyeler WHERE uye_kadi = '$kadi' and uye_sifre = '$sifre'";
                    $query = mysql_query( $sqlQuery );
                    if ( mysql_num_rows( $query ) > 0 ) {
                        $_SESSION[ 'login' ] = 'true';
                        
                        //İf correct username and password always coming here.I need location same page(this page.And I must running this code require_once "inc/default.php"; )
    /*Line 47*/                   header('Location: '.URL);
                    } else {
                        echo "<font color='red'>Böyle bir yönetici bulunmuyor.</font>";
        
                    }
        
                }
        
            }
        
            ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="tr">
        <head>
        <title>
        <?= SITE_AD." "?>
        Yönetim Sistemi</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/kokontrl/images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/kokontrl/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/kokontrl/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/kokontrl/vendor/animate/animate.css">
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/kokontrl/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/kokontrl/vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/kokontrl/css/util.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/kokontrl/css/main.css">
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
        
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        </head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="limiter">
            <div class="container-login100">
                <div class="wrap-login100"> <span class="login100-form-title" style="margin-top: -70px;color :#57b846">
                    <?=SITE_AD?>
                    Yönetim Sistemi </span>
                    <div class="login100-pic js-tilt" data-tilt> <img src="assets/kokontrl/images/img-01.png" alt="IMG"> </div>
                    <form action="" class="login100-form validate-form" method="post" >
                        <span class="login100-form-title"> FİRMA GİRİŞ PANELİ</span>
                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Kullanıcı adı boş geçilemez">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="kadi" >
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span> <span class="symbol-input100"> <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span> </div>
                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Şifre girilmemiş">
                            <input class="input100" type="password" name="sifre" autocomplete="new-password">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span> <span class="symbol-input100"> <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span> </div>
                        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                            <input type="submit" class="login100-form-btn" value="GİRİŞ YAP" name="yolla">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-t-12"> </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-t-136">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!--===============================================================================================--> 
        <script src="assets/kokontrl/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
        <!--===============================================================================================--> 
        <script src="assets/kokontrl/vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script> 
        <script src="assets/kokontrl/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <!--===============================================================================================--> 
        <script src="assets/kokontrl/vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script> 
        <!--===============================================================================================--> 
        <script src="assets/kokontrl/vendor/tilt/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script >
                $('.js-tilt').tilt({
                    scale: 1.1
                })
            </script> 
        <!--===============================================================================================--> 
        <script src="assets/kokontrl/js/main.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php } ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

[image]
Updated 12.08.2021 17.22 utc +3

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525251/header-location-not-working-in-my-php-code

Comment: They are tell add ob_start and ob_end_flush.Bu ı have already this.But not working

Comment: Then, insert a JS script instead

Comment: How can ı do this.Please can you give me example code?

Comment: Create a file `index2.php` where you put: `<?php require_once "inc/default.php"; ?>`. And on line 47 do: `echo "<script>window.location.href='index2.php';</script>"`

Comment: Please watch this error video.I was just now uploaded. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPadxCWNE6A

Comment: On line 47 try: echo "<script>setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, 3500)</script>"

This will reload the page after 3.5 seconds. If this works, you can decrease the number.

Comment: Thank you bro. İt's working :)

Comment: <script>setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, 3500)</script>";   it worked

Comment: Now u can replace 3500 with 500 and try if this works too. If it does work try also: `echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";`

Comment: Thank you <3 <script>location.reload();</script>";  İt's very nice bro

Comment: But sometimes hesitation. Why ? I added this post photo

Comment: How long is the delay in seconds? How long would it take normally without `location.reload()` ?